# How to rename a file via sftp using one-liner?

Tags: sftp

Is there a one-liner to use "sftp" to move a remote file on a remote server to another directory (on the same remote server)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `sftp` it is `rename`. If you ask for sftp invocation, using bash it's something like

```
sftp -b - host <<<"rename a/file b/file"
```